# How to change CSS property in Magnific Popup

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, popup, magnific-popup

I am using the Magnific Popup plugin. My code is as follows -

```
        $(".event").magnificPopup({

            items: {

                src: ".hidden-div",
                type: "inline"
            },
            closeBtnInside: true
        });
```

The thing is the ".hidden-div" section which I am trying to popup has it's CSS display property set to none as I want it to be visible on the page only through the popup.

So is there a way to set it's display property to say 'block' when above script is executed and set it back to 'none' when the popup is closed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fyi, by design you should add `mfp-hide` CSS class to element that should be hidden. Magnific Popup will automatically toggle it on open/close. http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#inline_type

Comment: Ok. Will give that a try too !

Comment: The method in my answer works too, but this is surely better and straightforward !

Answer (score 1):

This is the way it is working now. Basically I refered the API [here](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api)

```
$(".event").magnificPopup({

            callbacks: {
                open: function(){

                    $(".hidden-div").css("display", "block");
                },
                close: function(){

                    $(".hidden-div").css("display", "none");
                }
            },

            items: {

                src: ".hidden-div",
                type: "inline"
            },
            closeBtnInside: true
        });
```

I hope it is of use to others too !
Slightly off topic, really like the plugin !